# Animated element always on top ignoring z-index value

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a school assignment where I'm getting weather data and displaying the output, in the background I wanted some clouds moving around.

I coded the cloud movement with a CSS3 key frame, my problem is that the clouds always stay on the top even though the element I want on top have an higher z-index.

I was able to get it working correctly setting `.forecast` to `position: absolute;` but that element should stay in the middle of the screen and therefore I cant use absolute on that one.

The site: [beta2.sampettersson.com](http://beta2.sampettersson.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try position: relative; for the .forecast div

```
.forecast {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just move the #clouds div to higher in the source order (i.e. before the forecast div) it will automatically fall behind the forecast div.